# How to deal with default values of input fields in a table in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to automatically set the slugInput and versionInput inputs to different values for a table of things. How can I do this from a data structure?

Here's my view:

```
<div ng-controller="FileListController as flc">
    <h1>Files Available</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Slug</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="file in files">
            <td>{{file}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="slugInput"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="versionInput"></td>
            <td><button type="button" ng-click="packageMod(file, slugInput, versionInput)" class="fa fa-check btn btn-success"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question?   I'm not sure what you mean by "it's not possible to have multiple elements with a model that have different values"...

Comment: Are you looking for: `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="slugInput" value="{angularvariable}">`?

Comment: give an example with values of what you are trying to achieve. It's not clear to me either what you want to accomplish

Comment: @Grallen that works? News to me, I thought the value attribute didn't work.

Comment: Reworded the question, is it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple small changes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in files">
    <td>{{file}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="file.slugInput"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="file.versionInput"></td>
    <td><button type="button" ng-click="packageMod(file)" class="fa fa-check btn btn-success"></button></td>
</tr>
```

I changed the arguments to `packageMod`. You can access the values in `packageMod` with `file.slugInput` and `file.versionInput`. If you need to set default values ahead of time, loop through your files and set the values accordingly.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Thanks for pointing out the object route.